# How secure is JavaScript based HMAC?

Tags: javascript, hmac

I am currently architecting a new SaaS based application which will include a RESTful API.  I want to secure the communications between the Browser and API Server. To do this I plan on using a "Two Legged" OAuth approach.  My question is how secure can this approach be if I am encrypting in the browser using JavaScript HMAC library?  Wouldn't this approach expose the secret key?

Comment: Protect what exactly from whom? "Security" isn't an absolute thing, it requires at least two participants and a description of something worthy of protection.

Answer (score 1):

General observations about client-side Javascript based "security":

- anything you do on the client in Javascript is entirely visible to said client; you cannot hide anything from the user
- yes, if you're sending out private keys to the client in Javascript, they cease to be *private* keys
- anything happening client side cannot be trusted, at all; you don't even have any proof that the client is running *your* code, all you see is the result of it
- if you're trying to do some client-side magic to protect from third parties: a third party in a position to do any harm is typically also in the position to intercept all the Javascript that your server is sending to the client in the first place...
- if you're protecting the transport of said Javascript from said third parties by using SSL... you don't need any more client-side Javascript code to add any more protection to that channel

Beyond this, I'm not entirely sure who is supposed to authenticate against whom here and what you want to keep secret from whom; but hopefully these points will get you thinking.

Comment: I think you guys missed the gist of the question.  My question is how do you encrypt something in the browser without exposing the private key in the clear. At this point, I think I know the answer, but  thanks for the input none the less.